# Can't get javascript slider to animate

Tags: javascript, html, css

Works fine in Codepen but not on the website. Code - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPMKpv

This is the exact code I'm using so I have no idea why it shows as a static image on the website. Here: http://www.cubadupa.co.nz/

Any ideas? Also how can I make the transition between slide softer. Like with a slight fade in/out?

I'm new to JS so any help would be awesome.

```
<p>thnaks</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it has anything to do with your problem, but have you tried fixing the errors that come up in Developer Tools when you load the site? I personally see 3 connection refused errors for images and one bad element for masonry: null.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade the jQuery library. The branches 1.x and 2.x no longer receive patches.

Comment: I have upgraded to 3.1.0 but that hasn't fixed the issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think i found the problem.It's because you have adblocker on. Pauze or disable the adblocker and the slider will work.